# How to find the volume with the revolution around the $y$ -axis

Tags: calculus, volume

i need to find the volume formed by rotating the equations around the y axis. My equations are $x=2y$ and $x=y^3$. I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Would you be more comfortable rotating the region bounded by $y=2x$ and $y=x^3$ about the $x$-axis? It is the same problem, with the roles of $x$ and $y$ interchanged.

Comment: The graphs of these equations enclose some area in the first quadrant and an equal area in the third quadrant. Depending on whether you are supposed to consider only $y > 0$ or all $y$, the result can vary by a factor of $2$. Probably you were only meant to look at $y>0$, but it should be confirmed just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

$y^3-2y = 0 \to y(y^2-2) = 0 \to y = 0, \pm \sqrt{2}$. Due to symmetry, we can consider $y \geq 0$. Thus: $V = 2\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}} \pi\left((2y)^2 - (y^3)^2\right)dy$

Comment: Okay so I think I see how you got the integral. When I solve I get 13.5402. Does that seem right?

Comment: Please check with Wolfram Alpha to be sure.